# Using variable for post id in Facebook delete request PHP

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am using

```
$access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
            $response = $facebook->api(
            $post_id['id'],
            'DELETE'
            );
```

to delete a post from a Facebook page. I have the post id stored in mysql database and use

```
 $ad_id = osc_ad_id();
$conn = getConnection();
    $get_id=$conn->osc_dbFetchResult("SELECT * FROM %st_post_id WHERE ad_id = '$ad_id'");
    $post_id = $get_id['post_id'];
```

to retrieve the id.

When I test it on my site and press the delete button it comes up with

> Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.

Although if I do it manually, and make `$post = '5768877877667657_76576687667'` (fake id) then change the code

```
$access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
                $response = $facebook->api(
                $post_id,
                'DELETE'
                );
```

it works and deletes the post.

So my question is what is the difference between retrieving the id from mysql and doing it manually (`$post_id = '576768687878_7676765857875'`.

My row settings on mysql are type: varchar, collation: utf8_general_ci, and length: 50.

I have researched on stackoverflow for the solution but can't find anything.

I have also retreived the id on another page and then used echo to see if the format is correct, and it works, I even copied the echoed id and made `$post_id` equal to it, and it successfully deletes the post.

The request only fails when I retreive the id from the database and make it equal a variable.

Answer (score 0):

mysql functions are deprecated, Please use mysqli functions instead. In your code.

```
$post_id= msql_query("SELECT * FROM %st_post_id WHERE ad_id = '$ad_id'");
```

$post_id will be a result set. If you want to get each column of the result set . You need to use either mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_row(). So please add this code to get post_id and try to run your script.

```
 $post_sql= msql_query("SELECT * FROM %st_post_id WHERE ad_id = '$ad_id'");
 $post_details = mysql_fetch_array($post_sql);
 $post_id = $post_details['id'];
 $access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
            $response = $facebook->api(
            $post_id,
            'DELETE'
            );
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the code in my question as I only place msql_query so viewer won't get confused. Not sure if you're familar with the Osclass script, but instead of using mysql, it is simply just osc_dbFetchResult.

Comment: I am not  familar with the Osclass script.

Comment: Ok, as mentioned in the question I can successfully get the id and echo it on a page, so the fetching is not the problem. When I make '$post_id = $get_id['post_id'] this is where is doesn't work. If I make '$post_id = '46565657_4635656'' (fake code) then it works.

Comment: can you just try with putting the value in a single quote like this : $post_id = "'".$get_id['post_id']."'";

Comment: Getting Fatal Error: Uncaught OAuthException (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: " thrown in [has path to base_facebook].

Comment: can you please try this : $params= array(
                  'access_token' => $access_token
                );  $response = $facebook->api('/'.$post_id, 'DELETE', $params);

Comment: Getting an unsupported delete request error, same error in the question. So I tried going to MySQL database and copying the id to entering it manually like before ($post_id ='858484488_58484757', and it worked.

Comment: ok dear.. can you try $response = $facebook->api("/$post_id","DELETE"); $post_id in double quotes